# getElementsBy the first span in a class

Tags: jquery, html, innerhtml, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I have tried changing the HTML text of the first button in HTML using the following and it worked:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
list.innerHTML = "AAA";
```

But I am looking for a better solution where I can specify the exact "location" of the button. For example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('filter. > .btn-group > button').innerHTML = 'AAAA';
```

The snippet is given below:

```js
var list = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
list.innerHTML = "AAA";


//I am looking something like the below:

//document.getElementsByClassName('filter. > .btn-group > button > span > .multiselect-selected-text').innerHTML = 'AAAA';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter">

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button><ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="0"> AA</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> BB</label></a></li></ul></div>

<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="None selected"><span class="multiselect-selected-text">None selected</span> <b class="caret"></b></button><ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu"><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="0"> AA</label></a></li><li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="1"> BB</label></a></li></ul></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You need `document.querySelector`. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: you tagged jQuery. But, the code is native JavaScript. Are you looking for jQuery solutions? If not, please remove the tag

Comment: @Mojtaba Yes. I prefer jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a querySelector:

```
document.querySelector('.filter > .btn-group > button').innerHTML = 'AAAA';
```

Comment: Between the filter class and the btn-group I have a select tag and another class called filter1 It does not work if I add the filter1 class

Answer (score 1):

However, the jQuery solution could be any of these:

```
$(".filter > .btn-group > button").html("AAAA");
```

Or

```
$(".filter").children(".btn-group").children("button").html("AAAA");
```

Or, any similar combination.

I recommend take a look at this [short article](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-find-and-children-in-jquery/)

Also, if you have more than one `button` under `.btn-group` and you want to impact only the first one, you could use [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/). like this:

```
$(".filter").children(".btn-group").children("button").first().html("AAAA");
```

Comment: @Motjaba That changes the name for every button though. But that helps for future reference.

Comment: @ApoloRadomer, it does exactly what the previous answer does. I updated the answer to show you how to select the first `button`. Maybe that is your purpose

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)